# how to detect black spots and draw over them?

Tags: java, android

I'm developing android application and on my layout I have one image with black spots(dots) and now I want to detect this black spots and draw buttons over them and make buttons clickable. How can i detect this black spots(dots) and draw them programatically in Java(not Kotlin)?

Here is the example of one image. Thank you very much!
[Click here to view example of one image with black spots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsORr.png)

P.S. I don't want to use external libraries.

Comment: it will not work without external library.

Comment: Do you just want to make the black dots interactable?  Then the best way is not to use buttons-  use a custom image view and override the touch handler with something that implements hit detection.

Comment: Okay, thank you. So If I put this image in layout and over them I set ImageButtons when I start application on smaller screen sizes all this buttons are wrong placed (sometimes is under black spot, sometimes next to the black spot) but when I start app on larger screens it's all good.

Comment: I just want to put the Image buttons above the first picture, on first picture are black dots, I must cover this black dots with Image Buttons, but this must works on all screen sizes without moving Image button right or left...

Answer (score 0):

Unless you reimplement an image pattern recognition algorithm, I don't see.
Maybe you have another way to get black spots positions, at their creation for example ?

Comment: I have problem because now I draw Buttons over black spots in xml layout. But when I open app on smaller screens (4" or 4.7") they are not on the right place (sometimes they are below black spot, or next to the black spot).